# Error highlighting package for sublime text 3

Tags: ide, coding-style, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any package in `sublime text 3` for highlighting error while writing code (similar to Error Lens Extension in VS Code).

Comment: Yes, there are many. What language(s) are you using?

Comment: C++ (for competitive programming)

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is *linting*. Search [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) and you'll get lots of hits. The LSP package and sub-packages usually work quite well, as do the SublimeLinter ones.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much